# AutoIt - Where is the HotKeySet method?

Tags: c#, wpf, pinvoke, ui-automation, autoit-c#-wrapper

We are using AutoItX3.dll

Auto It's documentation states there is a HotKeySet method which would probably be the solution to a particularly painful problem we are experiencing.

http://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/functions/HotKeySet.htm

When I look at the available methods within the .dll, however, there is nothing related to HotKeySet.

Anyone recommend where to find this method?

Comment: The DLL provided by AutoIt does not contain all the functionality provided by the scripting language. That might be why you arent seeing the HotkeySet function since it is available only from the scripting language

Comment: thanks...

The main issue at hand is I already have a hotkey registered in our system.  The problem is, AutoIt is randomly sending the actual keypress instead of honoring the fact that a hotkey has been registered.

I was hoping to use the HotkeySet to actually disable a rogue character that AutoIt is sending.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`HotkeySet` uses a callback to a user defined function, converting the method for use in other languages isn't really worth the effort.

Instead you will have to call the WinAPI directly. Google search for `RegisterHotkey C# wpf` gets a lot of results. The [first result](https://www.outcoldman.com/en/blog/show/240) I've used before.